# How to detect that a controller has been called by g:include tag lib?

Tags: grails, gsp

In order to send appropriate response, I need to **detect whether the controller action has been requested by a classic HTTP GET request, an AJAX request or a [g:include](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html) tag lib**.

For instance, considering the following snippet code:

```
class CommunityController {
  def show = {
    def users = getUsers()
    if (/* WHAT IS THE CODE HERE??? */)  //g:include request => render 'show' template only
      render template:'show', model=[users]
    else if (request.xhr)  //Ajax => we send JSON content
      render users as JSON
    else //Classic request => we render 'show' GSP page
      [users]
  }
}
```

...how can I detect that the action has been called via a g:include tag lib?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test it like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils

if (request.getAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI_ATTRIBUTE)) {
    // request was included
}
```